# How to get table note labels to appear in normal but not superscript text using the threeparttable package?

Tags: tables, footnotes, superscripts, threeparttable, tabularray

I want the notes in my table to appear in normal text and one after the other without the classic line break.

In the `tablenotes` environment I used the `online` and `para` options, but it didn't have the expected effect (`\begin{tablenotes}[para,online]...\end{tablenotes}`).

I use the `tabularray` package to make the table, but I use `threeparttable` for the notes, although I know that there is the `talltblr` environment in the `tabularray` package (this is just for personal reasons).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\caption{The caption}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={XX}}
\hline
Text & Text \\
\hline
Text & Text \\
\hline
\end{tblr}
\begin{tablenotes}[para,online]
\item[ex] example
\item[ex2] example 2
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In `threeparttable`, whatever you put below `\end{tblr}` (or any other declaration of the end of an environment) and however you format it is your choice. For instance:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{threeparttable}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \caption{The caption}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={XX}}
      \hline
      Text & Text \\
      \hline
      Text & Text \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}\vspace{3pt}
    \par ex: example
    \par ex2: example2

    or:
    
    \begin{itemize}[nosep]
    \item[ex:] example
    \item[ex2:] example 2
    \end{itemize}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]